# What is the tense of "You should do that."?

Tags: grammar

What is the tense of "You should do that."? Also, what about the tense of if-conditionals.

Comment: It does not have a tense. It is a modal auxilliary, which in English are not inflected for tense.

Comment: "should" is a "modal" verb. In your case I'd say it's Present Tense "conditional mood", but I'm sure there are many different terminological schemas